# Minizinc: given array of results, ensure indexes with matching value also match according to an additional value

Tags: arrays, constraints, minizinc

A random `1..7` options for `1..13` positions model below produces an example output

`[3,2,2,3,6,7,1,4,2,4,5,2,3]`

I want to constrain it so that if the value is the same, then another value stated within another associated parameter array must also match.

```
set of int: optA = 1..7;
set of int: position = 1..13;
enum optB = {A,B,C,D};

array[position] of optB: opts = [A,A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D];
array[position] of var optA: result;

constraint forall(i in positions)(
  forall(j in optA)(
    % NO IDEA HOW TO FORMULATE EQUALITY HERE, IF THIS IS EVEN THE RIGHT IDEA
  )
);
```

In other words, if `result[1]`, `result[3]`, `result[8]` and `result[9]` are each assigned a `4` from `optA`, and second constraint looks at whether they have matching values from `optB`, which in this case they don't, so the result is invalid.

Any of `A,A,A` cannot have the same `optA` values as any of `C,C,C`, while within their set they can all be the same or different.

So, with this additional constraint, a valid solution could be

`[1,2,2, 3,3,4,4, 5,5,5, 6,6,7]`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `if the value is the same`  mean (what value?, and compare to what?), preferably by some example.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand how this connects to the first array in the description (`[3,2,2,...]`). I guess that the solution `[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]` is not a valid solution...

Comment: Sorry, realised my first edit isn't actually what I'm getting at. Hopefully the new edit explains it better.

Comment: What would be a valid solution?

Comment: Woops, had to redefine it a bit from the start to give enough of a range to properly show what I mean. I hope it's right now. `[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4] ` would also be valid, but I am also working with other constraints that limit the number of times a value can appear, which I haven't described here. Trying to break down and comprehend the parts of a larger model.

Comment: Is the _order_ of `result` relevant or is it just the number of A's, B's etc that is relevant?  E.g. would `[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]` be a valid solution?

Comment: It would not since `1..13` are entities that can be added to sets that have the same `optB` value but cannot be in the same set as those with another `optB` value. `[1,2,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]` has those with 'A' `optB` values having matching `optA` values with those with 'B' `optB` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that might be what you want. I understand this as the `A`s is a chunk (set) that can take any value, but not the values that are in the chunks of `B`, `C` or `D`.

The approach here is to simply check that if `opts[i] != opts[j]` then `result[i] != result[j]`. It that what you want?

```
set of int: optA = 1..7;
set of int: position = 1..13;
enum optB = {A,B,C,D};

array[position] of optB: opts = [A,A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D];
array[position] of var optA: result;

constraint
   % ensure that the "chunks" are different
   forall(i,j in position where i < j) (
      if opts[i] != opts[j] then
         result[i] != result[j]
       else
         true
       endif
   )
;
solve satisfy;

output [
"result: \(result)\n",
];
```

There's a lot of solutions (namely 2102520 solutions). Here are some of them:

```
result: [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
----------
result: [3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
----------
result: [3, 3, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
----------
result: [3, 3, 3, 7, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
----------
result: [3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
----------
```

Comment: Thank you! I will review this, as well as your answer to my other post, and will give you a massive up-vote when I have! I suspected there was a conditional requirement, but I am new to MZ so hadn't come across a conditional formulation of `forall` (apart from the background theory using `( ... | ...  where ...)`, which I understood as implying that the 'where' was implicit, somehow), as well as how to properly build an `if` statement that simply states `true` as a condition.

Comment: Still fewer solutions than 13^7 :) or is that 7^13? ;)

Comment: What reduces it is that elements `1..13` are given only a few options within `1..7` which they can take...

Comment: It's 13 (positions) ^ 7 (possible values). It's called "constraint programming" for a reason. :-)

Comment: If I can ask, what is `i` and `j` in `(i,j in position where i != j)`? Is `j` 'any other one'?

Comment: `i` and `j` are the two loop variables. The loop could be written as `forall(i in positions, j in positions where i < j) (....)`; perhaps that helps to understand it.

Comment: So does including the `j` variable increase the size of the loop, because it has to go through all of those positions that are greater than `i`, before it moves on to the next value of `i`, which again is tested against all value greater than it, as compared to a 'basic' `(i in positions)` loop?

Comment: Is this functionally equivalent to running a `forall()` within a `forall()`? Not that I am able to write out an example of it. I am still adjusting from Javascript style loop manipulation and syntax.

Comment: I see your point about `i != j`. It can be written as `i < j` (and I'll change it).

Comment: And yes, `i,j in positions` is a shortcut of a traditional nested `forall` loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234785/discussion-between-mikeyb-and-hakank).